# ¿Como puedo detectar que presionaron la tecla ImpPnt una aplicación?

Tags: c#

Buenas tardes señores,

¿Existe alguna forma de poder detectar cuando un usuario ha presionado la tecla `ImpPnt`?

Lo que estoy queriendo implementar es el poder detectar el momento en que un usuario ha presionado la tecla `ImpPnt` o `PrntScrn` desde cualquier control dentro de cualquier formulario que este dentro de un módulo y/o aplicación.

La aplicación donde necesito implementar esto tiene varios proyectos, algunos de ellos están desarrollados enteramente en VB y otros en C#.

Atentamente,
Juan Manuel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si puedes implementar el evento keyup ejemplo:

C#:

```
    private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyValue == 44) {
            MessageBox.Show("haz presionado la tecla de imprimir");

        }
    }
```

VB:

```
    Private Sub Form1_KeyUp(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyUp

    If e.KeyValue.Equals(44) Then
        MessageBox.Show("haz presionado la tecla de imprimir")
    End If

End Sub
```

ojo esto funciona siempre y cuando el form tenga el focus.

Saludos...

Comment: Lo que me comentas se hace para un form en particular, pero si quiero hacerlo a nivel aplicación? Si tengo varios proyectos relacionados, poder capturar esa tecla a nivel aplicación. No se si eso ayuda un poco más. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que main es tu formulario principal:

```
            AddHandler main.KeyDown, Sub(o, e)
                                          If e.KeyCode = Keys.PrintScreen Then
                                            'Aqui tu código
                                          End If
                                      End Sub
```

Asegurate de que la propiedad *KeyPreview* en el formulario esté en verdadero.